# python unittests assertEqual print too much when it fails

Tags: python, assert, error-logging, nosetests, python-unittest

In a bunch of tests that I'm running using `nosetests`, an `assertEqual(a,b)` fails, `a` and `b` (pretty long strings) are printed verbatim filling the screen, obfuscating everything else. You can create similar situation by adding this to one of your test cases:

```
def test_my_long_strings(self): 
    self.assertEqual('a'*5000, 'b'*5000)
```

I tried setting `--verbosity=0` and `--debug-log=File`, but none of them had any effect, and the two strings are still printed on the screen.

Is there anyway to shutup the `assertEqual` verbosity or redirect it to a separate file other than stderr (where test failures/passes are also reported)?

Comment: See [unittest.TestCase.maxDiff](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.maxDiff).

Comment: can you put the code of the problematic test? And the output? What is `too much`?

Comment: @Oz123: I haven't really counted the number of characters in the two strings. I looks like to be hundreds of 80 char lines. You can create a similar test like this:

def test_my_long_strings(self):
    self.assertEqual('a'*5000, 'b'*5000)

The test is not really a unittest, but rather an end-to-end test based on unittest module (not written by me, I'm a user trying to debug it).

Comment: @LukasGraf this is very curious indeed. assertEqual is calling assertMultiLineEqual for strings, which must be controlled with  unittest.TestCase.maxDiff whose default value is 8*80=640 based on the documentation. But running the above example with default maxDiff, all 5000 characters are still printed on my machine.

Comment: @user2442366 I checked again, `maxDiff` only affects the *diff* output (the `+/-` part). The strings that are displayed as part of the exception with the default assertion message are not affected by it. So you'd have to use a combination of `maxDiff` and what @Jimr proposes in his answer.

Comment: @user2442366 in order to do this, you'd probably best create your own subclass of `TestCase`, something like `SilencedTestCase`, set the class variable `maxDiff`, and extend `assertEqual` on it to always provide a custom assertion message that truncates your strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

assertEqual takes as a third parameter an assertion message for failure.

```
class TestMyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        a = 'a'
        b = 'b'
        self.assertEqual(a, b, 'a did not equal b')
```

prints the stack trace of the failing location plus

```
AssertionError: a did not equal b
```

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual